# How to create a new text file to write to in objective c ipad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

How would I go about creating a new text file in my program so that I can write content to it? I already understand how to write content but I haven't been able to find anything (anything easy to understand) on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
                  usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc
                         error:(NSError **)error
```

An example:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example"
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:&error];

if(error) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"ERROR while loading from file: %@", error);
}
```

Write to a file works this way:
Use this method:

```
 - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path 
          atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile 
            encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc 
               error:(NSError **)error
```

Example:

```
[text writeToFile:path atomically:NO  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Mistake:

Can't just write to bundle path. Need to copy it to Documents Directory.

```
-(void)copyBundleToDocuments
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Example.txt"];
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *bundlePlistPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Example.txt"];

        NSError *error;
        BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePlistPath toPath:documentPlistPath error:&error];
        if (success) 
        {
            [text writeToFile:documentPlistPath atomically:NO  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        }
}
```

Comment: Just a though, make sure that the `path` in `writeToFile:` is not pointing to the read-only main bundle.

Comment: gd point -> forgot about that. Can't write to read-only path... will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so broad one could drive a truck (or lorry, in UK English) through the middle of it.

But in general, you could add a UITextView to one of your view controllers.

And when you are ready to save, you could take the contents of the text view (which is a NSString), and save it to a file via the NSString writeToFile methods.

And you can load the text view later on via NSString's "initFromFile" method, as long as you know the path to that file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530422/how-to-save-text-in-uitextview-for-iphone) [are other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995482/save-text-from-uitextview) [that people have asked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uitextview+save) that may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextView to write text

save the file using

```
     [txtView.text writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Get the TextFile content using

```
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
```

Comment: But this would only work for a text file that already exists, wouldn't it?

Comment: you can create new text file using writeTofile this will write yor text into file...